# How to avoid hard coding resource paths in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and want to know if there's a standard way to avoid hard-coding paths to resources (like js and css files) in HTML templates. Is there any standard way to set up mappings between names and file paths in a centralized location, so instead of writing

```
<script src="~\My\File\Path></script>
```

I can do something like

```
<script src="myfile"><\script>
```

and the location of myfile will be found according to the name-path mapping? It would also be nice if there was a standard way to do this for partial views. I could probably put something together for this if necessary but I was wondering if there's a best practice way of doing it.

Comment: [Using Bundling and Minification with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Honestly, the preferred way of doing this in my opinion is to not use the MVC bundling and to use the more utilized and common JS tools like gulp to do the bundling/minification for you.  Then you hardcode just the one resource for CSS and the one for JS.  Any changes you make to your source files will trigger the gulp watch task, or you can manually trigger it in command line or in Visual Studio.  Keeps you on the same tech as the front end team, and if its just you (i.e no front end team) you are using modern front end tools and practices

Comment: @maccettura can you please elaborate, or if not do you know of any good resources to learn more? Thank you for your help